# C Function Infinite Loop issue

Tags: c, function, infinite-loop

I believe there is a simple solution to my issue, but my brain is too fried to think right now.

Inside my main function I have a function we will call "Function1". In "Function1" I call another function that verifies the data in "Function1", lets call this "Function2". In order for "Function2" to do its job well, it needs to call "Function1" again. This is obviously how I am getting an infinite loop of "Function1" and "Function2" repeatedly calling each other. I need to create method for tracking this so I can stop the loop after the first pass of Main --> Function1 --> Function2 --> Function1 --> End, but my implementation keeps failing.

I greatly appreciate any help and guidance.

Comment: "A piece of code says more than 1000 words". Care to share the code for the functions? That should improve your odds to get a useful answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass in a level counter to function1. On the first call the level is 0. If the level is 0, it can call function2. If it > 0 then do not call function2.
When function2 calls function1, it sets the level to 1 (or increases it).
This is how you do recursive calls. You can, of course, change the end condition to something else as needed (instead of just 0 and 1).

Comment: thanks, I believe I knew this I just kind of needed to talk it out. I appreciate the help

Answer (score 1):

You could set a counter integer, and only run Function2 when the counter is less than 1 (or however many times you'd like the loop to iterate before breaking out).

For example (pseudocode):

```
int count;

  Function1{  
    ...  
    while(count < 1){  
      Function2{  
        ....     //Function2 code
        count++;  
    }  
  }  
  ..   //any code from Function1 that should run after Function2  
}
```

(Note, you could also do this with a boolean if you'd like - I prefer the integer approach, as you can change the number of iterations before breaking out fairly easily)